# Is it possible to store the slapd SSL certificate data inside the cn=config directory itself?

Tags: openldap

Though I like the cn=config style of slapd configuration it seems odd to still have to place the SSL certificate files outside of the directory on the hosts file system.

I'm talking about:

```
dn: cn=config
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/CA.crt
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/certificate.crt
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/certificate.rsa.key
olcTLSDHParamFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/dhparam
```

Is there already a way to place that information inside the directory - to not depend on paths of the hosts file system?
Or is there a reason for not putting that information into the directory?